# Why macOS is pointing to two versions of python 3?

Tags: python, macos, macos-sonoma

Good that MacBook now shipped without the dead `python2.7`.

I have python 3 installed already:

```
 % python -V
Python 3.9.6
```

However, I a create an isolated virtual environment, I get `Python 3.11` instead.

```
python -m venv venv
```

Which means packages installed in the environment go into `venv/lib/python3.11`.

By this I cannot scripts using:

```
python my_script_file.py
```

But

```
python3 my_script_file.py
```

Should I completely remove `Python 3.9.6`? And for any future release, possibly means removing `Python 3.11`?

What is the pythonic way to handle this?

**UPDATE**

Apparently, I have 2 versions installed:

```
% python -V
Python 3.9.6

% python3 -V
Python 3.11.6
```

Comment: If you execute `python -m venv venv` with Python 3.9.6, you will get a venv with Python 3.9.6. If you are getting a venv with 3.11, you have skipped something crucial in your explanation.

Comment: If you create a Python virtual environment, you should use the Python interpreter installed for that virtual environment, not the one installed globally in the system.

Comment: If you run `type python` and `type python3` you will found out what you are actually running when you use each command.

Answer (score 2):

You can create venv for specific versions right?

like

```
python3.9 -m venv venv
```

or

```
python3.11 -m venv venv
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to specify the version using

> py -3.11 main.py

to work with that particular version of python if you don't want to uninstall it